# Ubuntu crashes every time after launching Houdini 19.5.640 does it need additional libraries because I am running from a external SSD?

Tags: drivers, ssd, crash

I have been trying to install Houdini and Unreal engine in Linux because it is faster and more robust.
So far I was able to finish setting up correctly but after started working with the applications no matter which (Houdini or Unreal engine) it crashed the whole Ubuntu and after few seconds it will throw me off to login screen. I log back in try to launch Houdini it will behave same.
I checked stats of GPU CPU and RAM it is detecting everything. Nvidia drivers are also installed.
it is showing GPU (nvidia-smi) in terminal.

Am I missing anything to install or update in Linux that is required by these two applications?
Or the problem is external SSD which is SanDisk extreme portable SSD 1TB (1gbps)?
I cannot rely on windows because Houdini works better in Linux.

Comment: You've provided no clues as to what Ubuntu product, what release of that product, nor what messages you actually obtained (*nor if you explored the crash report*). Currently we'd be guessing as you've provided too few specifics (*which includes how you installed Houdini too*).

Comment: @guiverc It is the Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I downloaded Houdini Launcher after installing Launcher I installed Houdini 19.5.640 through it. Launcher installed Houdini in /opt/
But it also crashed without launching any of the heavy appplication. I was using firefox and it was crashing.